# Upload local SQL Server 2008 database to web server within particular time

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to upload data from a local SQL Server 2008 database to web server database within particular time.

I.e. suppose my database runs on local host and some inserts, updates and deletes are performed on local database. Now I want to upload that data to the web server.

How it will happen?

Both database are structurally identical.

Comment: refer msdn website :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use sql server Copy database functionality.

Connect to Database server >> Right Click on any one database >> click on TASk >> Select Copy Database.. Option..

This Sql Copy Database wizard will copy your whole database from one server to another server. you can copy this to you webserver also.

Hope this will help you..

Referance:

[Referacen 1 Step by Step..](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/27/sql-server-copy-database-from-instance-to-another-instance-copy-paste-in-sql-server/)

[Referance 2 From MSDN..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it manually (for example, using a program like http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) or you can make scripts/applications that do it for you.

Then you can either run those script manually or set up various automated jobs to do it, in various types of software (deploy managers, windows jobs, sql server agent jobs etc).

Basically - you're asking a general question about how to deploy a solution/change, and well, a ton of different methods exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Sql Jobs](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2139/sql-server-agent-job-management/). Create a script that will select data from your local database and insert it to remote database. Now schedule the as per your convenient time interval when your load is lesser on local server. Also you have embed some mechanism in the sql script , so that you can identify from where to start the next execution. Like DateTimeStamp or id of last record selected anything based on your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Script the database then execute the T-SQL create database script on the hosted instance server:

[image]